# Get batch from collate_fn of Pytorch data loader

Tags: python, pytorch

I am reading video and split them into batched. I cant fit a whole video in my batch. So i split them using collate function. Shape of video is (128,3,224,224).
Where 128 is frames, and 3 is channels (RGB).
Output shape from data loader after using collate function is
torch.Size([4, 32, 3, 224, 224]) where index 0 is batch. I if pass this bath data , if will get memory error. Is there a way to send a batch of 2 .?
Here is the code for reproduce-ability purpose.
**Generate dummy data**

```
features=[]
labels=[]
#here the data is in ram, but actually its in disk and i cant load all data to ram to manipulate. 
for i in range(5):
    features.append(np.random.randint(low=0, high=256, size=(128,3,224,224)))
    labels.append(np.random.randint(low=0, high=2))
```

**dataset**

```
class DataReader(Dataset):
    def __init__(self,features,labels):
        self.features = features
        self.labels = labels

    def __getitem__(self, index):
        x=self.features[index]
        y=self.labels[index]
        return x,y
        
    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.features)
```

**dataloader**

```
def reshaped(i,bs=32):
    i=i[len(i)%bs::].reshape(len(i)//bs,-1,3,224,224)
    return i
def collate_fn(batch):
    data=reshaped(batch[0])
    print(data.shape)
    label=[batch[1]]*len(data)
    return data,label
dl=DataLoader(DataReader(features,labels), batch_size =None, num_workers=0,pin_memory=True,shuffle=False,collate_fn=collate_fn)
batch=next(iter(dl))
```

batch[0] shape is `(4, 32, 3, 224, 224)` even with a single batch the generated data is large, so i want to send `(2, 32, 3, 224, 224)` then another `(2, 32, 3, 224, 224)`

Dont get confused with `batch=None`, i am just disabling automatic batching. Practically `batch=None` load one batch. I convert that one batch to four batches in collate function.
But the issue is that now all four will be sent further and i want only 2 of them to be sent, then next 2 to the model, instead of all four at once.

Answer (score 0):

Based on my understanding, **collate_fn** would be called every time whenever your model is forwarding. So, every time just take current element and next element in the batch. This might not correct,could you try this out? Please let me know the result.

```
def collate_fn(batch):
    data = batch[0][0: 2] # current element and next element in the list
    label = batch[1][0: 2]
    return data,label
```

Comment: the issue with this approach is that it will keep only first 2 and discard rest of

Comment: What would happen if using batch_size=2 in the DataLoader, isn't that what you want?

Comment: output will `(4*2, 32, 3, 224, 224)`

Comment: could you explain a bit about your def reshaped?